# When using the Clip method to play a sound, how do I get it to terminate

Tags: java, playsound

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException{
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    File file = new File("Agent P Jingle.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioStream);
  
  clip.start();
    
    String response = scanner.next();
  
}
```

I don't know how to make this piece of code terminate, I'm using it to play a sound but after the sound is finished playing and it just goes silent and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?
Once you type in 'stop' it terminates:

```
AudioInputStream in = null;
Clip clip = null;
try {
    File file = new File("Agent P Jingle.wav");

    in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(in);

    clip.start();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    while ((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            break;
    }

    scanner.close();

    clip.stop();
} catch (Throwable tr) {
    tr.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (clip != null) clip.close();
        if (in != null) in.close();
    } catch (Throwable tr) {
        tr.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(You could also use Java's automatic resource management for closing both the clip and the stream)